# Reading from XML file with processing instruction and writing to another output file

Tags: java, xslt-1.0

I am having an input xml file with PI's like below

```
<A>
  <B some data>
      <?C?> 
        Some data is there
       <?D?>
         <E>
          <F>
          <G>
     </A>
```

I want to read this input XML and write to another file with below conditions.
1. The content from input XML from  to  should be written to the output file only if the processing instruction is present in the file.

Please provide your suggestions either using Java or XSLT 1.0

Comment: can you please clarify? whats your conditions, processing instructions, etc...

Comment: We dont provide you with solutions here, please post your work, what you have tried and where is that you are finding it difficult to do this